# Phonegap / Converting website for mobile use

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, mobile-website

Currently I am building an app using phonegap for the Android and iOS systems. Essentially, it will be a website but I am running into some difficulties due the cross domain requests I need to make via ajax (same origin policy). Im wondering if its better to make the website on my own servers, where PHP is allowed, and then use a wrapper/frame in phonegap to emulate the site? How would that work?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be having this problem at all.  PhoneGap apps are loaded on the device as local file:// pages, and the cross-domain security policy does not apply to them.

From the PhoneGap FAQ:

> Q. I want to create an application for phonegap to access externally deployed web services via AJAX. How can i resolve the issue with the
>   cross-domain security policy of XmlHttpRequest?
>
> A. The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply.
>   (in Android,you may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the AndroidManifest.xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with cross-domain requests then consider using something like jsonp as the data interchange format.  Where are you requesting the data from?

Comment: Right, I know jsonp can be used. But would it be easier to just code the web-app on my own servers, using php, and then use a wrapper or frame to display it in the app?

Comment: That would be no problem, but then you don't need PhoneGap.  It will simply be a regular website... which you can make look like a native app by putting its launcher icon on the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a PHP proxy for a cross domain service so that you can access it with your mobile app using phonegap?  This is a pretty common thing, its done a lot in Flash as well to get past cross domain restrictions.

For one of my demos I need to access Google Images from Flash.  To do so I created a VERY simple PHP proxy on my server called imageproxy.php.  Here's the complete code:

```
<?php
readfile($_POST['url']);
?>
```

Yep, thats its.  So in your case, if you were using this PHP proxy on your server, you would send this proxy your target URL as a post variable and the proxy makes the request and returns the response via readfile().

Comment: Right, but I couldn't do that in phonegap because they don't allow PHP in your app? How would I access the remote php script? Using JSONP?