# How to display json feed to user?

Tags: json, jquery

I have a valid json feed that I am pulling from the server by accessing a php file using jquery. An example of the json feed returned from querying the php file is

```
{"items":[{"acc_number":"11111","acc_name":"TestAccount","demographics":["Some
Street","SomeState","99999"],"last_thirty":null,"phone":null,"sms":null,"email":null},    {"acc_number":"22222","acc_name":"MyAccount","demographics":"MyStreet","MyState","99999"],"last_thirty":null,"phone":null,"sms":null,"email":null}],"total_items":"80","md5sum":"c7a834d45bdf348abfdcdb95994c7608"}
```

I am using the code below which I though would go through feed and bring down all of the records and fields that were not NULL. But I am not getting anything.

```
$.ajax({
   type= 'GET',
   url: 'http://MyURL.com',
   dataType: 'json',
   username: myusername,
   password: mypassword,
   success: function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key,val) {
        items.push('<li id="' = key = '">' + val + '</li>');
});

$('<ul/>', {
   'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
} 
});
}
```

Any help/tips is appreciated as always.

Thanks!

Updated based on answers below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  testNews();
});

function testNews() {
$('body').append('<h1>News</h1>');
$('body').append('<h2>Main Display</h2>');
$('body').append("<div id='success_news_main' class='waiting'>Waiting for response</div>");

$.ajax({ 
type: "GET",    
url: 'http://MyURL.com/news.php', 
dataType: 'json',
username: myusername, 
password: mypassword,
success: function(data) {
    var ul = $('<ul/>').addClass('my-new-list').appendTo('body');
    $.each(data.items, function(k,v) {
    $('<li/>').attr('id', k).html(v).appendTo(ul);
});
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use string concatenation when forming the html tags for display. Instead use jQuery's functions create the dom elements, add attribute values to them and add them to the page.

Here's a suggestion on modifying your code:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type= 'GET', 
   url: 'http://MyURL.com', 
   dataType: 'json', 
   username: myusername, 
   password: mypassword, 
   success: function(data) { 
        var ul = $('<ul/>').addClass('my-new-list').appendTo('body');
        $.each(data.items, function(k,v) {
            $('<li/>').attr('id', k).html(v).appendTo(ul);
        });
    }
});
```

This is also easier to read and doesn't look through the array twice.

Also, the "v" variable within "$.each" will be the objects of the array within the json. You'll need to access their individual properties and create the necessary html/elements within the li instead of setting it directly as the html property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. Your solution above works nicely. I am getting a list of the correct number of items with just the bullet point showing. Your comment above about accessing individual properties is there a resource you could point me to to read or give an example. I am assuming thats why the values ar enot displaying. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try iterating over `data.items` and not over `data` as this is your collection:

```
success: function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

    ...
}
```

Also your `items.push` method seems broken with those multiple `=` characters. You probably meant `+`.

Another remark is the val variable inside the `$.each` statement. It will be an object. You probably want to select a specific property from this object, like:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.acc_number + '</li>');
```

And the key will be the index of the array. And because ids in HTML cannot start with a number if you want to have valid HTML you might need to prefix your li id:

```
items.push('<li id="item_' + key + '">' + val.acc_number + '</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail and fast answer. I updated my code based on your suggestions above and others below but still get the waiting for response message based on the code updated on my question. I am also using this with phonegap and jquery mobile so not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I put error: alert('FAILED'), after dataType and I am getting the failed message both in FireFox and iOS simulator. So it looks like the URL might be the issue.

Comment: @Deon, how can you possibly put an alert after dataType? You put it either before/after the $.ajax call or inside the success callback. Also I have noticed that you are using an absolute url: `http://MyURL.com`. Make sure that you are not violating the same origin policy restriction which forbids you from sending AJAX requests to different domains. The best way to ensure this is to use relative urls, like this: `url: '/myscript'`.

Comment: Am I going about this wrong? Is there another way to query this php file and get the json feed? When I use the URL in the browser I can put in the user/pass and the json feed shows in the body. It might be cross-domain but I am also pulling an xml feed from the same server and no issues with that. Thanks for all your help. I will keep trying to troubleshoot and use console.log to see where it is stopping.

Comment: @Deon, is the url you are trying to access with AJAX hosted on the same domain as the domain that server the page containing this javascript?

Comment: No it isn't: I am using it in xcode to build a webapp so it is calling that url from local machine

Comment: Using PhoneGap I don't have the cross-domain issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797613/phonegap-converting-website-for-mobile-use

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `data.items` since the JSON returns the values in that array. This code example also fixes "=" where "+" should have been.

```
$.ajax({
   type= 'GET',
   url: 'http://MyURL.com',
   dataType: 'json',
   username: myusername,
   password: mypassword,
   success: function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key,val) {
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });  


        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('body');
   });  
});
```